# Nock: No match for request

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, nock

My nock call looks like as below

```
app_url='myshop.app.com'
result = nock(app_url, {
            reqheaders: {
                 "content-type": "application/json",
                 'authorization': 'Basic Auth'
            }
          })
        .get('/admin/products.json?collection_id=10001&limit=250&fields=id')    
        .reply(200, {
                "products": [
                { "id": 101},
                {"id": 102},
            ]
        });
```

Resolve :

```
(node:1378) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Nock: No match for request { .
```

But now,

==========updated=============

I have updated my call which is not throwing an error but now it is not intercepting the request....It is still hitting shopify to fetch the data

Comment: what was the solution ?

Comment: Consider adding a solution otherwise this is a very confusing post. How did you update your call?

Answer (score 5):

Just add flag in scope { allowUnmocked: true }

```
nock('https://host.com', { allowUnmocked: true })
    .post(`/path`)
    .reply(200, {answer: "any"});
```

Comment: This is not right, it should be the other way around. You should not allow unmocked URL.

Comment: For this case, check if there are no unnecessary body params being passed incorrectly: Example: `.post(\`/path/${id}\`, unecessaryBody)` should actually just be  `.post(\`/path/${id}\`)` or the opposite, it requires a body param and you are not passing

Answer (score 1):

This happens when a nock matching the URL being hit is not found.
The url being hit is

> https://myshop.app.com/admin/products.json?collection_id=201&limit=10&fields=id

as seen in the error message.
The URLs you are nocking do not correspond to it.

Something like this should work.

```
app_url = "https://myshop.app.com/"
result = nock(app_url, {
        reqheaders: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
        }
    })
    .get('/admin/products.json?collection_id=201&limit=10&fields=id').
    .reply(200, {
        "products": [{
            "id": 101
        }, {
            "id": 102
        }, ]
    });
```

More details about the exact way to nock can be found in the [Nock Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nock).

Comment: @user269867 Thats bad. Just noticed the trailing ',' in the products array, not sure if that creates issues.

Comment: @user269867 Any luck with the , removal ?

Comment: No, I changed some config not ","

Comment: @user269867 Can you elaborate the config change that you made for it to work ?

Comment: This is not working and also no information of what you changed to make it work!!

Answer (score 0):

The nocked URL must be exactly the same as the URL that would be executed by Node in order to avoid the 'Nock: No match for request' error. So all you need to do is:

```
nock('https://host.com')
 .log(console.log) // log the mocked URL so that you will know if they're 
                   // the same or not.
 .post(`/path`)
 .reply(200, {answer: "any"});
```